# cakephp validations not working

Tags: validation, cakephp

i have the following form:

```
    <?php   echo $this->Html->image('itemdefault.gif',array('class'=>'image1'));    ?>
    <?php   echo $this->form->input('quantity',array('class'=>'input'));    ?><br>
    <?php   echo $this->form->input('SpecialInstructions', array('type'=>'select','style'=>'font-size:13pt;width:120px;','options'=>$spec_ins));    ?><br>
    <?php   echo $this->form->input('Ingredients',array('class'=>'input'));     ?><br>
    <?php   echo $this->form->end('Save',array('class'=>'button1'));
```

and this is the validation in the model:

```
var $validate=array
(
    'quantity'=>array
    (
        'numeric'=>array('rule'=>'numeric','required'=>true,'message'=>'Enter numbers only'),
        'qty_must_not_be_blank'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Quantity cannot be left blank')
    ),
    'Ingredients'=>array
    (
        'body_must-not_be_blank'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Body must not be blank')
    )
);
```

but none of the validation is working. is it because the fields do not exist in my database?

Comment: How do you know that validation is not working? How did you test?

Comment: Put more details in your question for clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Form->create();
```

is missing from your code. Try include it at the beginning of your code

Comment: it is there in my code...i just forgot to paste it in my snippet here.

Comment: Ok, is your data saving correctly? Could you also provide the controller code, please?